# Installing python with IDLE

Tags: python, idle-python

I used the `synaptic package manager` to download the following:

`python(was already installed), libpython3.2, python3.2-dbg, idle-python3.2, '
 python3.2- minimal(was already installed)`

When I run the `IDLE` I type a simple line like 
`print "some sample text"`

And I get a syntax error. 
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 20:13:42) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
==== No Subprocess ====
>>> print "some sample text"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there's nothing wrong with the package you installed, you are trying to use python 3, check the [what's new page](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html) to see the differences, one of them is that:

> The print statement has been replaced with a `print()` function, with keyword arguments to replace most of the special syntax of the old print statement (PEP 3105). Examples:
>
> ```
> Old: print "The answer is", 2*2
> New: print("The answer is", 2*2)
>
> Old: print x,           # Trailing comma suppresses newline
> New: print(x, end=" ")  # Appends a space instead of a newline
>
> Old: print              # Prints a newline
> New: print()            # You must call the function!
>
> Old: print >>sys.stderr, "fatal error"
> New: print("fatal error", file=sys.stderr)
>
> Old: print (x, y)       # prints repr((x, y))
> New: print((x, y))      # Not the same as print(x, y)!
> ```

Comment: LOL I'm an idiot. Ty!

Comment: @Evandro Yep, that's right. I think we just posted our answer at a time. anyway, let's leave it as it is for confirmation :)

Comment: @Achu yeah, but since the interpreter was running fine and python gave a `SyntaxError`, everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

In python 3, `print` is a function. You need to use it just like `print("some sample text")`